# How to store into the local storage ? (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, input, local-storage

I have a question for you... On my react app, I have a `<input></input>` but I would like the user to be able to keep his message thanks to the local storage.

```
class Profil extends Component {
    message() {
        if (localStorage != 'undefined'){
            document.getElementById('message').value = localStorage.getItem('message');
        }
        else {
            alert("localStorage is not supported");
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input name="message" onChange={() => this.message()}></input>
            </div>
        );
    }}
```

With that, when I put a letter, I have directly an error message :

```
TypeError: localStorage.getItem(...) is null
```

and this line is false :

```
document.getElementById('message').value = localStorage.getItem('message');
```

What do I have to do ?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('your value")
localStorage.getItem('message');
 use this line

Comment: I can see document.getElementById('message') selector but you have given mesage as name. You can use document.getElementsByName("instead") or change the name to id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the DOM manually, you could keep the message in state and update the localStorage value on every change, and also read the value from localStorage when the component is created.

**Example**

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: localStorage.getItem("message") || ""
    };
  }

  onChange = event => {
    const message = event.target.value;

    localStorage.setItem("message", message);
    this.setState({ message });
  };

  render() {
    return <input value={this.state.message} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In functional component in the following way we can able to store and restore the values from localstorage using **useEffect** hook

```
const mounted = useRef()
const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState({firstname: '', lastname: ''})

function supportsLocalStorage() {
    try {
        return 'sessionStorage' in window && window['sessionStorage'] !== null;
    } catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current && supportsLocalStorage) {
        const progress = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues'))
        if (progress !== null) {
            for (const x in formValues) {
                formValues[x] = progress[x]
            }
        }
        mounted.current = true
    } else {
        const filteredState = formValues
        localStorage.setItem('formValues', JSON.stringify(filteredState))
    }
}, [ formValues ])
```